# Facebook Application: "Add to my pages" dialog

Tags: facebook

In http://github.com/facebook/connect-js/blob/master/src/core/ui_methods.js methods.js documentation, there is the following note:

> "Consider putting complex UI methods
>   in their own modules."

Anybody knows if is possible to instantiate an "Add to my pages" dialog, based on Application Profile's link?

What is the name of the method?

Thanks,

And Past

Answer (score 0):

To add a application to your page you need to go to the url below:
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL

As the application profile's link is something as the following:
http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=APP_ID

You can just fetch the APP_ID from the url.

More reading from:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611

Comment: Yes, now they implemented an easy way to do this. When I posted the question 1/half year ago, the process was a few hard to execute. Nowadays, we already adapted our system for our needs and facebook improved code and documentation.